# How to Get Boolean value as output in SQL

Tags: sql, boolean

I have a Table as:

```
Col
1
1
1
0
0
```

and I want output to look  like:

```
True  False
3     2
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
sum(case when col=1 then 1 else 0 end) as True,
sum(case when col=0 then 1 else 0 end) as false
from input;
```

Comment: Thank you Ashima, initially it gave an error as True and False needs to be inside inverted Comma (' ').
select 
sum(case when col=1 then 1 else 0 end) as 'True',
sum(case when col=0 then 1 else 0 end) as 'false'
from input;

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(Col ) as "True",
    COUNT(Col) - SUM(Col) as "False"
FROM
    my_table
```

Comment: This feels really hacky when there's a more standard way to do it

Answer (score 0):

I would express this as:

```
select sum(col) as true, sum(1 - col) as false
from t;
```

This works as long as the values are `0`, `1`, or `NULL`.